# Text watcher in edit text is making the edittext slow

Tags: android, textwatcher

In my tablet app I have used fragments and one fragment has multiple Edittexts, and I have a linear layout which will add a sublayout as many times the user wishes to add, in that fragment

This sublayout has two edittext, both this edittext is having

1. addtextchangelistener(Textwatcher) and
2. onfocuschangelistner

every time the text is changed 3 conditions are checked in both the edittext
every time the focus is changed 2 conditions are checked in both the edittext

After doing all this condition check, the problem I'm facing is, the edittext typing is too slow, its like i type an email and the whole email gets completely typed after 5 secs or more,

This is the code for 1 edit text in the sublayout:

```
receiverName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View paramView, boolean hasFocus) {
            receivernameFocus = hasFocus;
            if(hasFocus)
            {
                if(receiverName.getText().toString().length()>0)
                    ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                else
                    ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            else
                ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    receiverName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1,int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {


            if(receivernameFocus)
            {
                if(receiverName.getText().toString().length()>0)
                {
                    receiverNamePresent = true;
                    ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    receiverNamePresent = false;
                    ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
            else
                ReceiverName_btn_cancel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            if(receiverEmailPresent && receiverNamePresent)
                addReceiver.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus_receiver);
            else
                addReceiver.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plus_deselect_receiver);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence,
                int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable paramEditable) {
        }
    });
```

same conditions are present for the other edittext, and everytime the user inflate another view, same set of edittext will be created for the new view too.

I can't remove the conditions, all of them are necessary, and you can see its just some button visibility or setting background resource

How to optimize this code, or how to speed up the edittext typing speed for android tablet?

EDIT: If I'm typing 10 letters persecond its showing only 1 letter per second in the edittext(so all the 10 letters will be visible in the edittext after 10 seconds), which I believe is happening because of multiple condition checking within onTextChanged method,  the delay in showing the text is too much for user experience.

How to make the edittext show the text as fast as I'm typing it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here `public void onTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1,int paramInt2, int paramInt3)` it's generally in this format:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
```

So here you will need to do some operation using `paramInt3` . If you would like to show suggest text will come after you enter 3 letter then perform an operation here in this manner:

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{

```
        if (count%3 == 1) 
        {
           adapter.clear();
           GetPlaces task = new GetPlaces();                   
           task.execute(dep_place.getText().toString());
        }
```

}

here I haved updated text from server side in background. You just need to modify this portion from where your text will come use this code here.

Thanks.

Comment: I just have to check everytime whether text is present in the edittext or not, I have checked the parameters what you have also mentioned, but typing speed is not improving

Comment: For typing speed I tell you the if(count%3==1) condition. It will show matching text after 3 letters

Comment: I don't need matching text, I just want to check whether text is present in the edittext or not

Comment: You will need use Adapter which adapt those text already in those editext and count will match from this editext.

Comment: Sorry I'm not using a listview, or I'm not using a adapter at all, please look into the question I asked, the typing speed within my edittext is very slow,if I'm typing 10 letters persecond its showing only 1 letter per second in the edittext, which I believe is happening because of multiple condition checking within onTextChanged method, my question is how to make the edittext show the text as fast as I'm typing it

Comment: Oho !! No no your any condition I think not hamper the typing speed. Generally emulator process typing speed slow and it's depend on device fastness . Would you test the apk any devices or only in the emulator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44486/discussion-between-ari-and-satyaki-mukherjee)

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee Did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm seeing the same thing. I have a TextWatcher and I also have a LengthFilter applied.